# Unwanted deletes from table

Tags: sql, join, azure-sql-database, delete-row

We are facing an issue in our DWH environment wherein records that should not be deleted from a table are getting deleted.

There are separate PROD and Dev DWH environments but they are like mirror image of each other with Stg,Pstg,Dim and Fact tables.
The staging table gets data from source system through an ELT process (in ADF).

There is a delete process setup in ADF environment that runs every day and copies the primary key of the table from source system into Stg table.
Then there is a stored proc that compares this key column value between Stg and Pstg table and deletes the records
that are present in Pstg table but not in Stg table(thus signifying records deleted from source as well).

Query used for deleting records in Stored Proc is :

```
DELETE T1 FROM PStgM1.Dhst T1 
LEFT JOIN StgM1.Dhst T2 
ON T1.[D_Id] = T2.[D_Id] 
WHERE T2.[D_Id] IS NULL
```

This query is being constructed dynamically, with Schema 1, Schema 2, Table Name and Primary Key names being passed to the stored proc as parameters.

The issue is that delete process is deleting records that are present in both Stg and Pstg table, this deletion does not happen every day but it is happening randomly. Also, delete does not happen in both the environments, some times records getting deleted only from Dev environment and sometimes only from Prod environment.
It is surprising that records are not getting deleted from the table in both environments at the same time.

There is no explicit Primary Key, Foreign Key defined in the Stg and PStg tables and there are no triggers defined on these tables.

Delete query is correct, I see no issues with this query.

I also checked which all objects are accessing this Pstg table, found that there are two objects - a view and a stored procedure.
There is no delete happening in these hence unable to determine why and where these records are getting deleted.

Also, checked from the ADF log that execution of delete stored procedure begins only after copy activity is completed,
hence issue cannot be that comparison between Stg and Pstg table begins before copy of all primary key records from source system is completed.

Also, whenever this delete process is run separately during testing it never deleted any additional records (that were not meant to be deleted).
Issue occurs when this delete process runs as part of daily load.

Any pointers in identifying the issue will be extremely helpful.

Comment: `This query is being constructed dynamically` ... not an answer, but note that as your schema and table names themselves are dynamic, you _can't_ use a prepared stored procedure here.  Best practice would be to not make the schema/table names directly dynamic.

Comment: You could have triggers.  My best guess, though, is that other queries are running that are doing the unwanted deletions.